# Confusion on using super with new style classes

Tags: python

I have this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

class myclass1(object):

        def __new__(cls,arg):
                print cls, arg, "in new"
                ss = super(object,cls)
                print ss, type(ss)
                ss.__new__(cls,arg)
#                super(object,cls).__new__(cls,arg)
#                return object.__new__(cls,arg)


        def __init__(self,arg):
                self.arg = arg + 1
                print self, self.arg, "in init"




if __name__ == '__main__':

        m = myclass1(56)
```

It gives an error:

```
$ ./newtest.py 
<class '__main__.myclass1'> 56 in new
<super: <class 'object'>, <myclass1 object>> <type 'super'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./newtest.py", line 23, in <module>
    m = myclass1(56)
  File "./newtest.py", line 9, in __new__
    ss.__new__(cls,arg)
TypeError: super.__new__(myclass1): myclass1 is not a subtype of super
```

The error is valid. I get that. However I am now confused as to what the documentation is saying on this page for __new__: http://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

**Question: What am I doing wrong as per the documentation above. Where is the gap in my understanding of the documention ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to replace `object` with `myclass1` in `ss = super(object,cls)`.  `object` has no superclass.  `myclass1` does.  You also need to remove `args` from `ss.__new__(cls,args)` as `object.__new__` has only one parameter `cls`.  Final code should be:

```
        def __new__(cls,arg):
                print cls, arg, "in new"
                ss = super(myclass1,cls)
                print ss, type(ss)
                ss.__new__(cls)
#                super(object,cls).__new__(cls,arg)
#                return object.__new__(cls,arg)
```

The gap in your understanding of the documentation is that the first parameter to `super` is the class of which you want to obtain its superclass.  Not the superclass itself.  If you already knew the superclass or wanted to hard-code for a fixed one, you could well have replaced `ss` with `object` and written:

```
        def __new__(cls,arg):
                print cls, arg, "in new"
#               ss = super(myclass1,cls)
                print object, type(object)
                object.__new__(cls)
#                super(object,cls).__new__(cls,arg)
#                return object.__new__(cls,arg)
```

Comment: I don't think thats right. If you look at the help for `super` you will see that `super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)`. So isn't the super call I am using the correct one?

Comment: From the documentation for super: If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is unbound. If the second argument is an object, isinstance(obj, type) must be true. If the second argument is a type, issubclass(type2, type) must be true (this is useful for classmethods). http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Comment: From the documentation (and omitting "or sibling" for simplicity):  "super(type[, object-or-type]) - Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent class of type."  Here, the word `type` refers to the parameter, not to the type of the parent class.  Trying to explain it, I realize the documentation is pretty ambiguous.  If they had called the parameter `a`, it would have been clearer.

Comment: You should do a help(super) in the interpretor and look at the valid super constructor calls. I bet they mean super(superclass, subclass).

Comment: `issubclass(type2,type)` is only **one** of the requirements of `super`, and not the reason why your code doesn't work.  The reason is that you are asking for the superclass of class object and that doesn't exist.  When you apply `__new__` to `ss`, class `super` tries to delegate/proxy it.  When it doesn't find an underlying class, it thinks the recipient is itself and fails as `myclass1` is not a subclass.

Comment: @abc  1)  I'm just trying to help you.  2)  There are at leasts 3 person who agree with my answer.  3)  The code I provided for you is working...  I don't know what else to say.

Comment: @abc  OK.  I found something else.  The same page of documentation contains an example.  `class C(B)` and then they use `super(C,self)`.  If what you say is right, shouldn't they be using `super(B,self)`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36186/discussion-between-abc-and-mario-rossi)

Answer (score 2):

Super is usually not used in `__new__` since `__new__` is a static method. At this point the object does not even exist yet so there is no super to call.

Refer to the [release notes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__) on the specific method to override `__new__`